# How do I concatenate multiple .npy ndarray files into one dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got a folder with 24 '.npy' files with ndarrays inside them(ndarray of face encodings). I want to create a for loop that goes through them and append it into a new data-frame. How do I do that? I tried to do this way but it throws an error :
zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

```
def convert_dataframe(data):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(data))

embed_path = "<path to folder>"
dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
for embeddings in embed_path:
    embed = convert_dataframe(embeddings)
    embed.append(dataframe)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the following:

```
import os
import numpy as np

embed_path = './path_to_folder/'       # Use forward slash (/) at the end

arr = []
for file in os.listdir(embed_path):
    temp = np.load(embed_path + file)
    arr.append(temp)

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that I need to load before I append. It now throws :
Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False
Any idea?

Comment: Try np.load(embed_path + file, allow_pickle = True)